# Using .pack() and .grid() at the same time with tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget

I have a program with some Label() widgets, some Button() widgets, some Text() widgets, and a few Entry() widgets. A couple of revisions ago, I didn't have the labels, and I had less Entry() widgets, and I mixed .pack() and .grid() as was convenient and I was fine. I had to do some refactoring, and added the extra widgets in the process - all the new things added used .grid(). Nothing about the other widgets changed. Now, I get an error along the lines of "unable to use grid in .", etc. (I can post the full error message if necessary). Why, and how can I fix this? (I can post code if necessary as well.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't mix `grid` and `pack` with widgets that share the same parent.

Why? Because `grid` will try to lay widgets out, possibly growing or shrinking widgets according to various options. Next, `pack` will try to do the same according to its rules. This may require that it change widget widths or heights.

`grid` will see that widgets have changed size so it will try to rearrange the widgets accirding to its rules. `pack` will then notice that some widgets have changed size so it will rearrange the widgets according to its rules. `grid` will see that widgets have changed size so it will try to rearrange the widgets according to their rules. `pack` will then notice that some widgets have changed size so it will rearrange the widgets according to its rules. `grid` will see that ...

Comment: Would you explain what you mean by "parent"? Apologies, I'm really new to tkinter.

Comment: @heather some people and documentation use the word "master". Widgets exist in a tree-like hierarchy. Every widget except the root widget have a parent.

Comment: @BrianOakley would you mind listing the parents of the widgets I'm using?

Comment: @heather: you've shown no code, so no, I can't. If you haven't explicitly set a parent (and you should), then the parent is the root window. If you didn't explicitly create a root window (and you should), one is created for you.

Comment: okay then, so basically I need to set different parents for the pack and the grid widgets - I have created a root window, but not explicitly created parents.

Comment: I just looked around SO and found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285648/can-you-change-a-widgets-parent-in-python-tkinter which seems to imply that you *can't* explicitly set a parent for widgets.

Comment: @heather: correct. _once a widget has been created_ you can't change the parent. However, _at the time the widget is created_ you must either give it a parent, or the parent will be set to the root window.