# How to keep widgets when a new tab(ttk notebook) is created?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, logic, ttk, ttkwidgets

So I have a starter tab which has a textbox inside. I also want to create a new tab on the click of a button. When I create the new tab it does not show the textbox. I want all the tabs to have the same textbox and the same widgets.

Here is my code so far:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")

def newTab(*args): # How do I keep the textbox and other widgets in the new tabs
    newFrame = Frame(root, width=500, height=500)
    newFrame.pack()
    tabsArea.add(newFrame, text="Untitled.txt")

button = Button(root, command=newTab).pack()

# Tab Area --- First Tab 
tabsArea = ttk.Notebook(root)
tabsArea.pack(pady=15)

# Create Main Frame 
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack(pady=5)

# Add Frame to Tab
tabsArea.add(frame, text="Untitled.txt")

# Textbox
textBox = Text(frame).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

How do I configure the text box and widgets in the newFrame/new tab?

Comment: Which one do you want actually: show the *same* widgets, or *duplicate* those widgets in the new tab?  If it is the first case, then it is not possible as stated in this question "[can-you-change-a-widgets-parent-in-python-tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285648/can-you-change-a-widgets-parent-in-python-tkinter)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a new text widget in each tab. Your code is just creating empty frames. Also, you shouldn't be calling `newFrame.pack()` since you are adding `newFrame` to the notebook.

Here is a slimmed down version of your code that shows the basic concept:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")

def newTab(*args): 
    newFrame = Frame(root, width=500, height=500)
    tabsArea.add(newFrame, text="Untitled.txt")
    text = Text(newFrame)
    text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

button = Button(root, text="New Tab", command=newTab)
tabsArea = ttk.Notebook(root)

button.pack(side="top")
tabsArea.pack(pady=15, fill="both", expand=True)

# Add the first tab
newTab()

root.mainloop()
```