# How to Move a button from one frame to another on click using tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout

I have 2 frames, one of them has a button "click". On clicking that button, the same button should be destroyed from the original frame and move to frame2. How to achieve it using tkinter.

Comment: You cannot *move* widget from one frame to another frame.  You need to destroy the widget from one frame and create new one in other frame.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you change a widget's parent in python tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285648/can-you-change-a-widgets-parent-in-python-tkinter)

Comment: What I really wanted to know is that if there is a way to destroy a widget from one frame and create a new widget with the same attributes as the destroyed one on a new frame. In this case the widget is the button and the text part of the newly created button should be the same as the destroyed one.

Comment: You can use `.config()` to get most of the configurations (not including reference to function) of the button.  Then use this configurations to create the button again.

Answer (score 0):

there is tow frames `frame1` and `frame2` first we want to show this button using `pack()`. now we want to add function on command of `my_btn` then we want to destroy that button and re define it in the second frame.

final code:

```py
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
frame1 = Frame(window, width=50, height=50, bg='red')
frame2 = Frame(window, width=50, height=50, bg='blue')
frame1.propagate(0); frame2.propagate(0)
frame1.pack(); frame2.pack()

def click():
    global my_btn
    my_btn.destroy()
    my_btn = Button(master=frame2)
    my_btn.pack()

my_btn = Button(master=frame1, command=click)
my_btn.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Hope this works.